# Filter for a specific record in Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I've this structure of Fire Database

[image]

If I need to find a specific box, I do in Angular

```
url = 'https://box-xxxyyy.firebaseio.com';

  getBox( box: string) {

    return this.http.get<any>(`${ this.url }/box/${ box }.json`)
      .pipe(
        map( res => {
          return res;
         } )
      );

  }
```

But if I need to find all the records that have "red" in the "color" field, how i do?

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the documentation on [filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering), you might come up with a query like this, using `orderBy` and `equalTo` query string parameters:

```
this.http.get<any>(`${ this.url }/box/${ box }.json?orderBy="color"&equalTo="red"`)
```